# Can I change owner of directory that is mounted on volume in IBM containers?

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to launch postgres in IBM containers. I have just created volume by:

```
$ cf ic volume create pgdata
```

Then mount it:

```
$ cf ic run --volume pgdata:/var/pgsql -p 22 registry.ng.bluemix.net/ruimo/pgsql944-cli
```

After logging into container through ssh, I found the mounted directory is owned by root:

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4096 Jul  8 08:20 pgsql
```

Since postgres does not permit to run by root, I want to change the owner of this directory. But I cannot change the owner of this directory:

```
# chown postgres:postgres pgsql
chown: changing ownership of 'pgsql': Permission denied
```

Is it possible to change owner of mounted directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In IBM Containers, the user namespace is enabled for docker engine. When, the user namespace is enabled, the effective root inside the container is a non-root user out side the container process and NFS is not allowing the mapped non-root user to perform the chown operation on the volume inside the container. Please note that the volume `pgdata` is a NFS, this can verified by executing `mount -t nfs4` from container.

You can try the workaround suggested for
[How can I fix the permissions using docker on a bluemix volume?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31750970/how-can-i-fix-the-permissions-using-docker-on-a-bluemix-volume)

In this scenario it will be

```
1. Mount the Volume to `/mnt/pgdata` inside the container

cf ic run --volume pgdata:/mnt/pgdata -p 22 registry.ng.bluemix.net/ruimo/pgsql944-cli

2. Inside the container

2.1 Create "postgres" group and user    
groupadd --gid 1010 postgres
useradd --uid 1010 --gid 1010 -m --shell /bin/bash postgres

2.2 Add the user to group "root"
adduser postgres root
chmod 775 /mnt/pgdata

2.3 Create pgsql directory under bind-mount volume
su -c "mkdir -p /mnt/pgdata/pgsql" postgres
ln -sf /mnt/pgdata/pgsql /var/pgsql

2.2 Remove the user from group "root"
deluser postgres root
chmod 755 /mnt/pgdata
```

Comment: Thanks, adding postgres user to the root group tentatively did the magic!

Comment: This seems to help tentatively but how would it look to make it permanent?  If I follow this and then start a new container I'm back to permission denied on the `pgsql` subdirectory.  I'm also using the `postgres:9.5` image which might make things a little different.

Comment: For reference I was not able to make this work using the official DockerHub postgres 9.5 image.  It required modification to the `docker-entrypoint.sh` file using some of the ideas above before things would work.

Comment: @krsyoung: Can you share what you did to make it work?

Comment: Hey @StanislavPalatnik, I uploaded an example of the changes I made here:  https://github.com/krsyoung/ibm-containers-postgres.  Let me know how you make out!

Comment: @krsyoung: Thanks! That was almost perfect. One issue is that the check for PG_VERSION fails because the "non-root" root is trying to access a postgres owned file. I just chmodded the pgdata folder to 744 before the check and back to 700 after. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

In your Dockerfile you can modify the permissions of a directory.

`RUN chown postgres:postgres pgsql`

Additionally when you ssh in you can modify the permissions of the directory by using `sudo`.
`sudo chown postgres:postgres pgsql`

Comment: Both did not work for me. Do you mean vanilla docker but IBM containers?

Comment: Both are applicable to vanilla containers. Ibm containers are the same thing

Comment: @ruimo are you still having this issue?

Comment: Yes, it seems that the file system for bluemix volume does not permit root user to change files owned by other user's...

Comment: @JeffSloyer, I encountered a similar issue and both of these solution do not work for me. I expected atleast the second one to work. I hooked up a tomcat container( that  I had handy) to the volume and sshed to the container. Issuing a chown resulted in permission denied message.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 3 different but possible solutions:

1. [Using a dockerfile and doing a chown before mounting the volume.](http://container-solutions.com/understanding-volumes-docker/)
2. [USER ROOT command in `dockerfile` before you do a `chown`.](https://serverfault.com/questions/641264/how-to-add-a-file-to-a-docker-container-which-has-no-root-permissions)
3. [Use `--cap-add` flag.](https://blog.docker.com/tag/docker-1-2/)

Comment: Thanks for info. 1, 2 did not work for me. Locating "RUN chown" before volume statement or adding 'User root' before "RUN chown" took no effect. For solution 3, I don't know how I can pass --cap-add option to "cf ic run" command...