# How can I fix the permissions using docker on a bluemix volume?

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud

In a container, I am trying to start mysqld.

I was able to create an image and push to the registry but when I want to start it, the `/var/lib/mysql` volume can't be initialized as I try to do a `chown mysql` on it and it is not allowed.

I checked docker specific solutions but for now I couldn't make any work.

**Is there a way to set the right permissions on a bind-mounted folder from bluemix?** Or is the option `--volumes-from` supported, I can't seem to make it work.

The only solution I can see right now is running mysqld as root, but I would rather not.

### Try with mount-bind

1. created a volume on bluemix using `cf ic volume create database`
2. try to run `mysql_install_db` on my db container to initialize it's content

   ```
   docker run --name init_vol -v database:/var/lib/mysql registry.ng.bluemix.net/<namespace>/<image>:<tag> mysql_install_db --user=mysql
   ```

`mysql_install_db` is supposed to populate the `/var/lib/mysql` and set the rights to the owner set in the `--user` option, but I get:

> chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql': Permission denied.

I also tried the above in different ways, using sudo or a script. I tried with `mysql_install_db --user=root`, which does setup my folder correctly, except it is owned by the root user, and I would rather keep mysql running as the mysql user.

### Try with volumes-from data container

1. I create a data container with a volume `/var/lib/mysql`

   ```
   docker run --name db_data -v /var/lib/mysql registry.ng.bluemix.net/<namespace>/<image>:<tag> mysql_install_db --user=mysql
   ```
2. I run my db container with the option `--volumes-from`

   ```
   docker run --name db_srv --volumes-from=db_data registry.ng.bluemix.net/<namespace>/<image>:<tag> sh -c 'mysqld_safe & tail -f /var/log/mysql.err'
   ```

`docker inspect db_srv` shows:

> [{   "BluemixApp": null,   "Config": {
>       ...,
>       "WorkingDir": "",
>       ...   }   ... }]

`cf ic logs db_srv` shows:

> 150731 15:25:11 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from
>   /var/lib/mysql 150731 15:25:11 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld
>   5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log) starting as process 377 .. /usr/sbin/mysqld: File './mysql-bin.index' not found (Errcode: 13)
>   150731 15:25:11 [ERROR] Aborting

which is due to `--volumes-from` not being supported, and to data created in the first not staying in the second run.

Answer (score 3):

In IBM Containers, the user namespace is enabled for docker engine. The "Permission denied " issue appears to be because the NFS is not allowing mapped user, from container, to perform the operation.

On my local setup, on the docker host, mounted a NFS (exported with no_root_squash option). and attached the volume to container using -v option. When the container is 
spawned from docker with disabled user namespace, I am able to change the ownership for bind-mount inside the container.  But With user namespace enabled docker, I am getting
`chown: changing ownership of ‘/mnt/volmnt’: Operation not permitted`

The volume created by cf  (`cf ic volume create ...`) is a NFS, to verify just try `mount -t nfs4` from container.
When, the user namespace is enabled for docker engine. The effective `root` inside the container is a `non-root` user out side the container process and NFS is not allowing the mapped non-root user to perform the chown operation on the volume inside the container.

Here is the work-around, you may want to try

1. In the Dockerfile

   1.1 Create user `mysql` with UID 1010, or any free ID,  before MySql installation. 
   Other Container or new Container can access mysql data files on Volume with UID 1010

   `RUN groupadd --gid 1010 mysql`

   `RUN useradd --uid 1010 --gid 1010 -m --shell /bin/bash mysql`

   1.2 Install MySqlL but do not initialize database

   `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y mysql-server && rm -rf /var/lib/mysql && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`
2. In the entry point script

   2.1 Create mysql Data directory under bind-mount as user `mysql` and  then link it as `/var/lib/mysql`

   Suppose the volume is mounted at `/mnt/db` inside the container (`ice run -v <volume name>:/mnt/db  --publish 3306...` or `cf ic run --volume <volume name>:/mnt/db ...`).
      Define mountpath env var

   `MOUNTPATH="/mnt/db"`

   Add mysql to group "root"

   `adduser mysql root`

   Set permission for mounted volume so that `root` group members can create directory and files

   `chmod 775 $MOUNTPATH`

   Create mysql directory under Volume

   `su -c "mkdir -p /mnt/db/mysql" mysql`

   `su -c "chmod 700 /mnt/db/mysql" mysql`

   Link the directory to /var/lib/mysql

   `ln -sf /mnt/db/mysql /var/lib/mysql`

   `chown -h mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql`

   Remove `mysql` from group `root`

   `deluser mysql root`

   `chmod 755 $MOUNTPATH`

   2.2 For first time, initialize database as user `mysql`

   `su -c "mysql_install_db --datadir=/var/lib/mysql" mysql`

   2.3 Start the mysql server as user `mysql`

   `su -c "/usr/bin/mysqld_safe" mysql`

Comment: I don't get it, from what you say it's a setting on IBM's side but I don't think I have any access to IBM Containers NFS settings. Would you have a suggestion or a workaround ?

I guess I could 'just' create a NFS container and export, and mount in other containers, but I'd think that's adding a layer to the '-v' option for not much.

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple questions here. I will try to address some. Perhaps that will get you a step further in the right direction.

--volumes-from is not supported yet in IBM Containers. You can get around that by using the same --volume (-v) option on the first and subsequent containers, instead of using -v on the first container creation command and --volumes-from on the subsequent ones.

--user option is not supported also by IBM Containers.

I see your syntax for using --user (I suppose on localhost docker) is not correct. All options for the docker run command must come before the image name. Anything after the image name is considered a command to run inside the container. In this case "--user=mysql" will be considered as  a command that the system will attempt to run and fail.

The last error message you shared shows that there is some file not found in the working dir which causes the app to abort. You may work around that by using a script as the command to run in the container which changes dir to the right location.

Comment: so you are saying that -v /var/lib/mysql is going to be persistent between all my containers ? or between runs ? or using -v database:/var/lib/mysql ?

the --user option is an option for mysql_install_db which is supposed to initialise the content in /var/lib/mysql, using the '--user' option given.

the last error is missing files because the 'mysql_install_db' in the first run populated /var/lib/mysql/ in the first container, but the data didn't follow in the second run, as opposed to what I understand from your suggestion.

Comment: -v database:/var/lib/mysql    is the syntax that should be used with IBM Containers. 
With that the /var/lib/mysql data is actually stored on the "database" volume. So the second container sees the data when it maps that same volume, again using -v database:/var/lib/mysql.

Comment: that's what I have been trying but I can't do a 'chown' in there, `chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql': Permission denied`. I also tried to target a specific file, for example running "touch /var/lib/mysql/testfile; chown mysql /var/lib/mysql/testfile" with the same result. I also tried to put those commands in a script, with and without sudo.

Comment: are you able to run that container on your localhost docker and do chown?