# Bluemix ic run chown: changing ownership Permission denied

Tags: mysql, containers, ibm-cloud

I created and pushed to Bluemix an image `wp-mysql` with the following Dockerfile

```
FROM mysql
ADD wordpress.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/wordpress.sql
```

I created a volume

```
sudo bluemix ic volume-create mysqlvolume
```

And now try to deploy a Bluemix container from that image using

```
sudo bluemix ic run -it -m 256 --volume mysqlvolume:/var/lib/mysql -e  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=whatever --name wp-mysql registry.eu-gb.bluemix.net/whatever/wp-mysql-image-in-Bluemix
```

But I get

```
chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql/': Permission denied
```

I think it's related to [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31290202/can-i-change-owner-of-directory-that-is-mounted-on-volume-in-ibm-containers), but I don't know how to map the solution to my case.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31750970/how-can-i-fix-the-permissions-using-docker-on-a-bluemix-volume/32373375#32373375) - that one seems to have the workaround mapped specifically to mysql, and may hopefully help :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition, here is a sample Dockerfile and entrypoint script that can be adapted to work with mysql - https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_volumes_ov.html#container_volumes_write