# Performance of IBM Containers Volumes

Tags: postgresql, docker, containers, ibm-cloud

I'm running a postgres 9.5 database in IBM Containers.  I modified the DockerHub image so that it will work with the Volumes feature offered by the Containers service (had to work around permissions issues related to this questions: [Can I change owner of directory that is mounted on volume in IBM containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31290202/can-i-change-owner-of-directory-that-is-mounted-on-volume-in-ibm-containers)).

However, I'm now seeing very poor performance.  For example, here is the latest output of running the removal of a newly initialized postgres db (~20MB), varies but I haven't seen anything faster than 3 minutes:

```
/tmp/vol/pgdata $ time rm -rf *

real    18m 1.38s
user    0m 0.00s
sys 0m 0.25s
```

Is it possible that I need to configure something different in the image/container to get reasonable performance?  Has anybody else had luck running a database on a Volume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the performance specified for your filesystem underneath that volume.

For example, for volume 'pgdata' do `cf ic volume inspect pgdata`, and you'll get output something like:

```
# cf ic volume inspect pgdata
{
    "fsId": "long-fs-space-uuid-here",
    "hostPath": "/vol/long-fs-space-uuid-here/pgdata",
    "otherSpaceVisibility": [],
    "spaceGuid": "long-fs-space-uuid-here",
    "volName": "pgdata"
}
```

You can then get a list of your fs objects with `cf ic volume fs-list`, which will give you output like:

```
# cf ic volume fs-list
Name                          Size   IOPS/GB   Created               State
long-fs-space-uuid-here       20     0.25      2016-03-04 14:44:49   READY
```

In this case, my file system object is specified for 0.25 IOPS/GB and 20GB - i.e. 4 IOPS.  For something like a db, probably better to recreate it on a new faster fs:

`cf ic volume fs-create myfastfs 20 4`

wait for the new file space to show as READY:

`cf ic volume fs-list`

and then recreate your volume on that faster fs:

`cf ic volume create pgdata myfastfs`

Comment: For the record I can confirm I'm running at the 0.25/IOPS via the output of `cf ic volume fs-list`.  Unfortunately I'm having issues with Containers right now so I'm unable to test the proposed solution to increase to 4IOPS.

Comment: I'm marking this as the accepted answer because n-fritze provides the right approach to improving the performance.  As a comparison, to initialize a postgres database took ~2hours with the original 0.25IOPS 20GB fie space.  Using the 4IOPS 20GB file space makes for a significant improvement to ~5 minutes.  Still not usable (takes about 3 seconds on my mac book) but might be helpful for other use cases.