# how to run chown in Bluemix container to write to a Bluemix volume

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud

I am trying to chown the mounted volume directory in a Bluemix docker container. My run.sh that is run after the container started states:

```
chown -R grafana:grafana "$GF_PATHS_DATA" "$GF_PATHS_LOGS"
```

I get the error:

```
Cchown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/grafana': Permission denied
```

Is there a way to make chown usable, or do i need to use chmod instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I change owner of directory that is mounted on volume in IBM containers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31290202/can-i-change-owner-of-directory-that-is-mounted-on-volume-in-ibm-containers)

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31290202/can-i-change-owner-of-directory-that-is-mounted-on-volume-in-ibm-containers and it is also documented here https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_troubleshoot.html#ts_vol_owner