# IBM Bluemix: Not able to mount the MongoDB container "/data/db" on the Bluemix host volume

Tags: mongodb, docker, ibm-cloud, docker-compose

I am trying to deploy a Mongodb docker container on Bluemix w/ data persistence but always getting the error when the system is trying to mount on the container "/data/db" on the host (Bluemix) volume and the container doesn't start. For the last 2 days, I have researched and tried multiple options, [including one for Postgres on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31290202/can-i-change-owner-of-directory-that-is-mounted-on-volume-in-ibm-containers), but still getting the same error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

> **Error:**  $ docker logs f450993a-4cc ;chown: changing ownership of '/data/db': Permission denied

**docker-compose file:**

## docker-compose.yml

```
 mongodb:
  container_name: mymongo
  image: registry.ng.bluemix.net/helpfull/mongo:3.2.10
  volumes:
    - mongodb:/data/db:rw
  ports:
    - "27017"
```

Comment: The answer in the link you provided for the Postgres question is the way to go. I've never tried that with docker-compose.yml though, but this is also what is documented here https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_troubleshoot.html#ts_vol_owner

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Israel.Zinc for the nice editing of the question and Alex for your suggestion. After playing little bit more with the script based on the [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31290202/can-i-change-owner-of-directory-that-is-mounted-on-volume-in-ibm-containers) about [Redis solution](https://github.com/krsyoung/ibm-containers-postgres) by [krsyoung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/851145/krsyoung), I was able to make it work in the following way. I am new to Docker/Bluemix so not sure if this is the right solution but it is working fine and I hope it will save time for some other people.

**Docker-compose:**

```
mongo:
  container_name: hfmongo
  image: registry.ng.bluemix.net/helpfull/hfmongo:3.4.2
  volumes:
    - mongodatabase:/data/db
  ports:
    - "27017"
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM mongo:3.4

COPY docker-entrypoint-bluemix.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint-bluemix.sh"]

EXPOSE 27017
CMD ["mongod"]
```

**docker-entrypoint-bluemix.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
set -x

if [ "${1:0:1}" = '-' ]; then
  set -- mongod "$@"
fi

if [[ "$1" == mongo* ]] && [ "$(id -u)" = '0' ]; then
    STARTTIME=$(date +%s)
    echo "START: hack for IBM Bluemix"
    chmod 775 "/data/db"
    adduser mongodb root
    echo "END: hack for IBM Bluemix"
    exec gosu mongodb "$BASH_SOURCE" "$@"
fi
exec "$@"
```

Comment: Is this working for you? I'm trying your approach and seeing the container Shutdown with empty logs.